# Adding forward text to email

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I'm having a slight problem with adding text to forwarding emails. This is my current code:

```
private void ForwardFunction(Outlook.MailItem email)
{
    Outlook.MailItem forwardEmail = ((Outlook._MailItem)email).Forward();
    Outlook.Inspector forwardInsp = forwardEmail.GetInspector;
    Word.Document forwardDoc = forwardInsp.WordEditor;
    Word.Range forwardRange = forwardDoc.Range(0,1);
    string forwardText = "This is some text";

    forwardRange.Text = forwardText + forwardRange.text
    newEmail.Recipients.Add("myemail");

    forwardEmail.Save();
    ((Outlook._MailItem)forwardEmail).Send();
}
```

I've gone through it and it does add the text to the range, but when I receive the forwarded email it doesn't contain any of the additional text. I've used similar code to edit current emails that the user is editing (New, Replies/Forwards, InlineResponses) with success, but the email being passed to the function is the currently selected email in the inbox. Not sure if this matters, maybe because it's not being edited by the user.

I couldn't find a specific way to add new text to a programmatically forwarded email.

Comment: Check out these 2 links in regards to troubleshooting your issue
also wrap your `.Save && .Send` methods around a try{}catch{}
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2652320 &&
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315008

Comment: I think you are sending the wrong email.  Try with forwardemail.Send

Comment: @Max Sorry, forward email is what I meant. The above isn't the exact code, but a quick summary. While trying to make my code a little more generic, I forgot to be consistent.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Thanks for links, but they didn't really answer the problem I have. Thanks for the try{}catch{} advice!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else interested in this, I ended up using the `.HTMLBody`. It seems that using the `.GetInspector` either gets the inspector of the `_email` instead of `fEmail` and you can't edit it or it gets the correct inspector but it can't edit it. Either way, using the `.HTMLBody` seems to get around it.

```
Outlook.MailItem fEmail = ((Outlook._MailItem)_email).Forward();
string forwardText;

forwardText = "class=MsoNormal>";
forwardText += "This is my forwarded message";
forwardText += "Bonus hyper link <a href='" + hyperlinkText + "'>" + hyperlinkText + "</a>";

var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("class=MsoNormal>"));
fEmail.HTMLBody = regex.Replace(fEmail.HTMLBody, forwardText, 1);
fEmail.Save();
fEmail.AutoForwarded = true;
((Outlook._MailItem)fEmail).Send();
```